# How to do notification in android?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am doing a helpdesk application on android. I want to implement a notification for unread tickets(customer suggestions or complaints). In iPhone version of this app, even if the app is not open a counter for unread tickets on the app icon itself, is it possible in android. If it so please help me to implement like iPhone otherwise help me to implement normal android notification for unread tickets.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

call this method

```
private void triggerNotification(String s) {
    CharSequence title = "Hello";
    CharSequence message = s;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService("notification");
    Notification notification;
    notification = new Notification(
            com.yourPackage.R.drawable.notification, "Notifiy.. ",
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        null, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, pendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(1010, notification);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

this may help:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html